# Typescript code works but throws Object is possibly undefined error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-3.6

I'm trying to implement a queue structure in my typescript class. I have a queue class.

```
class Queue implements IQueue {

private storage: number[] = [];

constructor(private capacity: number = 3) {}

enqueue(rssi: number){
    if(this.size() == this.capacity) throw new Error("Has reached max capacity");
    this.storage.push(rssi);        
}

dequeue(): number | undefined{
    return this.storage.shift();

}

size(): number{
    return this.storage.length;
}

signalMean(): number{
    var mean: number = 0;
    this.storage.forEach(rssi => mean = mean + rssi);
    return mean;
}
```

}

So I tried to initialize a queue:

```
var init = new Queue(3);
```

and use it to here

```
if(signals.get(sender.id) == undefined) signals.set(sender.id, init);
```

When I try to add this codes like in below:

```
  if(signals.get(sender.id)?.size() < signals.get(sender.id).capacity) {
        signals.get(sender.id).enqueue(sender.signal);
    } else {
        signals.get(sender.id).dequeue();
        signals.get(sender.id).enqueue(sender.signal);
    }
```

I get Object is possibly 'undefined'. error although I checked and initialized it with `if(signals.get(sender.id) == undefined) signals.set(sender.id, init);` line.

But when I control it with log it works... How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm confused, what object is possibly 'undefined'?

Comment: The queue that returned from signals.get(sender.id)

Comment: [Does this help?](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hooks-tww3e?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Assuming `signals` is a `Map`, you should 1) use `signals.has(sender.id)` to check if a key exists, and 2) If `has` returns true you should then call `get` *once* and save the returned object in a variable, don't call `get` several times with the same key.

Comment: I tried if(signals.has(sender.id)) { and moved my if blocks to here } but it says same things again. It's so weird. And also my data always flowing and sender changing instantly.

Answer (score 0):

> if(signals.get(sender.id)?.size() < signals.get(sender.id).capacity) {

The problem is, that with the safe-access-operator (`?`) you tell the compiler, that `signals.get(sender.id)?.size()` can be undefined. As a result you would compare this undefined value with the `<` operator. Easiest fix is to remove the safe-access-operator and handle the not existing case separately.

Comment: Actually it puts automatically. When I remove that and try to         **if(lastSignals.get(message.nodeId)!= undefined && lastSignals.has(message.nodeId)){** my if blocks like             if(lastSignals.get(message.nodeId).size() < lastSignals.get(message.nodeId).capacity)
 } it still throws same error. I did similar approach in my program there is no problem. But it was key and array and this is key and queue.